# Method sets for T and *T

Tags: methods, interface, go, receiver

The [Golang language specification states](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

Why is this? Why do the methods receiving `T` belong to the method set for `*T` but not vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#different_method_sets):

> If an interface value contains a pointer *T, a method call can obtain a value by dereferencing the pointer, but if an interface value contains a value T, there is no useful way for a method call to obtain a pointer.

By the way, a method with pointer receiver can change its receiver, just like it can change a pointer parameter. Passing a non-pointer receiver as a pointer one (assuming this is possible), allows the method to change it, which should not.

It is recommended to use one consistent receiver type for all methods of a type and avoid mixing pointer and direct receivers. It is also recommended to use pointer receiver for large types.

Comment: Excellent authoritative answer. Cheers.